# Getting hostname with java fails in latest jdk7

Tags: java

I've been getting hostname of the machine as follows:

```
InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
```

However, when I put latest JDK (jdk1.7.0_04), the code above simply return LOCALHOST. I checked /etc/hosts (its linux) and it says there:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost    redbull
```

It's been returning REDBULL until upgrade. So I changed that around putting

```
127.0.0.1    redbull    localhost
```

instead and it started returning REDBULL without a problem.

Is there a better way of making this work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, I thought about flagging this as a dup, but the only answers I find suggest that you use  `InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName()`.  Which, frankly, I think *should* return "localhost" in this case.  And those answers, I suppose, are correct, in that there's really no pure Java way of doing this (at least none that are portable back to older JREs.)

We use JNI to accomplish this.  We call `SCPreferencesGetHostName()` on Mac OS 10.4+, `SCDynamicStoreCopyLocalHostName()` on older Mac OS, `GetComputerName()` on Win32, `gethostname()` everywhere else.

You could, of course, simply call `/bin/hostname` on Unix machines or look at the environment variable `COMPUTERNAME` on Windows.  It's sort of a judgement call as to whether you feel better calling JNI or `exec`ing another program.

For what it's worth, the reason we don't call `gethostname()` on Mac OS is because Mac does a weird dynamic hostname thing, where `gethostname()` will return the reverse DNS of your primary ethernet device.  If I were to plug my Mac straight into my cable modem, I'd get a hostname of `customer-10-42-21-42` or whatever my cable provider decided to set as my PTR record in their DNS.  Instead, going to the preferences will get you a stable hostname that was determined by the user.

Comment: Yes, this does look like a duplicate but its not when you take a close look. I also agree that it should return LOCALHOST. However, with all previous version of JDK, it never did and hence "correcting" the logic at this point does seem to be counter intuitive. Using JNI to get something as simple as hostname seems like an overkill to me. Unless someone has a better solution or JDK provides with something more standard, I'll be using my "workaround" on this one.

Comment: I would tend to agree.  Deploying JNI, while certainly well-understood, adds another level of complexity to your build & deploy process.  And if this is the only JNI you need?  Probably overkill indeed.  It's strange that they would have changed this, the Java team tends to mark seemingly major bugs as "as designed" in order to keep backcompat.

Answer (score 3):

If you're not against using an external dependency from maven central, I wrote gethostname4j to solve this problem for myself. It just uses JNA to call libc's gethostname function (or gets the ComputerName on Windows) and returns it to you as a string.

https://github.com/mattsheppard/gethostname4j

@edward-thomson's answer above makes me thing I might have a bit more work to do to make it work well on MacOS though :)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem and when all the following lined up it worked. host name had to be appended with DOT local

```
$ scutil --get HostName
drums
$ scutil --get LocalHostName
drums
$ scutil --get ComputerName
drums

$ sudo hostname drums.local
$ hostname
drums.local

$sudo vim /etc/hosts
192.168.x.IP drums
127.0.0.1 localhost drums
255.255.255.255 broadcasthost
::1 localhost
fXXX::1XXX localhost

$networksetup -setv6off Ethernet

$ sw_vers
ProductName: Mac OS X
ProductVersion: 10.9

$ java -version
java version "1.7.0_45"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_45-b18)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.45-b08, mixed mode)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a known issue in the macosx port of JDK7u4.

http://java.net/jira/browse/MACOSX_PORT-564